# Micronaut - Multiple bean candidates found

Tags: java, micronaut

I have the following class structure

```
@Singleton
public class Parent{}
```

```
@Singleton
public class Child1 extends Parent{}
```

```
@Singleton
public class Child2 extends Parent{}
```

Now i have another class in which i want to compose parent like below

```
public class Test{
@Inject Parent P;
}
```

However this throws DependencyInjectionException complaining that there are two candidates Child1 and Child2 for injection here. Can't i just inject Parent class here considering its a concrete class?

Comment: You probably need a Qualifier https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#qualifiers

Comment: Qualifier would make sense if I am trying to inject an interface but what I am trying to inject here is a concrete class itself. I am not sure why it should be restricted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add @Primary on the bean you want to be injected by default